# Editing login html phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Does anyone know offhand which file or mySQL table holds the HTML for the login form in phpMyAdmin?  Boss would like to add his own special message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the file libraries\auth\cookie.auth.lib.php at Line 108 (Function PMA_auth)

Comment: Thank you!  All of my hunting had failed to find it!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using phpMyAdmin4 and it's a little different. ..libraries\plugins\auth\AuthenticationCookie.class.php. I added it to the line with 'Welcome to phpMyAdmin' in it, line 166 or just search for 'Welcome'.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering how to modify the HTML in the latest version (5.2.0), you can locate the corresponding twig files in the following directory:

```
/phpmyadmin/templates/
```

For example, to add a footer message to phpMyAdmin's login screen, modify this file:

```
/phpmyadmin/templates/login/footer.twig
```

There's additional/conditional template code, so be careful when editing/adding.

Finally, if you've set up a shared phpMyAdmin instance in order to tunnel in via a local address (e.g. `127.0.0.1:1234/phpmyadmin`), the files can be found here:

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/templates/
```